# Storing data from an entire row, Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

So I have a method that allows me to get the id of a certain item by using a name i already have in an SQL Database. How would I go about getting the entire row of information and storing each item in its own variable.

Method that only works with ID

```
public Cursor getID(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = " SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
    Cursor data = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}
```

And the method that gets the query and stores the result

```
Cursor data = mydb2.getID(name);
            int itemId= -1;
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                itemId = data.getInt(0);
            }
```

Using this method below how would i store all of the data in its own variable using this (or any other way to get data of entire row).

```
public Cursor rowData(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
    Cursor data = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}
```

I know this might be a dumb question, and I have tried looking at other questions, I have gotten this far I just don't know what to do next (I'm very new to Sq Lite databases and Android development)

Comment: So the question just to clarify is how would i create something like the 2nd snippet of code for the entire row.

Comment: Dude you should be using Realm, awesome!

Comment: @Remario Looks really cool! I'll probably end up checking it out after this project so I can start out fresh with Realm

Answer (score 0):

You'd use something like :-

```
    Cursor csr = instance_of_yourdbhelper.rowData();
    while(csr.moveToNext()) {
        long thisItemId = csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(yourdbhelper.COL_1));
        String thisName = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(yourdbhelper.COL_2));
        // etc for other columns
    }
```

**Notes**

- **yourdbhelper** is the class for your DatabaseHelper which is the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper (the assumption is that the above methods are from such a class, as this is a common usage of SQLite)
- **instance_of_yourdbhelper** is the instance of the DatabaseHelper class i.e. you may have `yourdbhelper dbhlpr = new yourdbhelper(parameters);`, in which case **`dbhlpr`** is the instance.
- This just overwrites the same variables (thisItemId and thisName) for each row in the cursor, although there is perhaps the likliehood that the rowData method only returns one row.
- You will likely encounter fewer errors using the **`getColumnIndex`** method as it returns the offset according to the column name. *Miscalculated offsets is a frequent cause of problems.*
- You may wish to handle a no rows returned situation in which case you can use `cursor.getCount()`, which will return the number of rows in the cursor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think this is exactly what I needed!